# Ruby model constructor gives Error: Wrong Number of arguments passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 6.0 on macOS.
My class is defined as following:

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize (symbol, name, type, listed_on, faceValue)
    @name=name
    @symbol=symbol
    @type=type
    @faceValue=faceValue
    @listed_on=listed_on
    p "Insde Constructor"
  end
end
```

I am trying to instantiate this from Rails Console

[image]

Even more weird stuff what I Observed is when I try to instantiate with different number of parameters I get following changed responses
[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Is there an `assets` table? Does this need to be an ActiveRecord?

Comment: "MAC" refers to a [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), not a "Macintosh computer".

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't mess with ActiveRecord's initialize method. Bad things happen, as you can see. Instead, use `attr_accessor` to add non-column fields.

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :symbol, :name, :type, :listed_on, :faceValue
end
```

This allows one to access both the columns and your extra attributes. For example, if the assets table has a column cost...

```
asset = Asset.new(
  cost: 12.34,   # set the cost column
  name: "Junk",
  type: :junk,
  listed_on: Time.current,
  faceValue: 0,
  symbol: :jnk
)
```

If you really need to mess with initialization, use the [after_initialize callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find).

---

If symbol, name, type, listed_on, and faceValue are all columns of the assets table, do nothing. ActiveRecord will take care of it.

```
class Asset < ApplicationRecord
end

asset = Asset.new(
  name: "Junk",
  type: :junk,
  listed_on: Time.current,
  faceValue: 0,
  symbol: :jnk
)
```

---

If there is no assets table, don't inherit from ActiveRecord at all.

```
class Asset
  def initialize (symbol, name, type, listed_on, faceValue)
    @name=name
    @symbol=symbol
    @type=type
    @faceValue=faceValue
    @listed_on=listed_on
    p "Insde Constructor"
  end
end

asset = Asset.new("Junk", :junk, Time.current, 0, :jnk)
```

But I would say to use named parameters so people don't have to remember what argument 4 meant.

```
class Asset
  def initialize (symbol:, name:, type:, listed_on:, faceValue:)
    @name=name
    @symbol=symbol
    @type=type
    @faceValue=faceValue
    @listed_on=listed_on
    p "Insde Constructor"
  end
end

asset = Asset.new(
  name: "Junk",
  type: :junk,
  listed_on: Time.current,
  faceValue: 0,
  symbol: "jnk"
)
```

This can be done more easily by including [ActiveModel::Model](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html). And you get a host of convenient things like [validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

```
class Asset
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :symbol, :name, :type, :listed_on, :faceValue

  validates :name, :type, :symbol, presence: true
  validates :faceValue, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
end

asset = Asset.new(
  name: "Junk",
  type: :junk,
  listed_on: Time.current,
  faceValue: 0,
  symbol: :jnk
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think things that inherit from ApplicationRecord usually have initialize functions, I believe they look for an appropriately named database table, `assets` in this case (table should be plural, modal singular), and get their fields from there.

Comment: This is likely the case. `ApplicationRecord` does a bunch if magic internally and the `initialize` method is *not* supposed to be re-defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ApplicationRecord you should not redefine `initialize`, you should instead pass in properties like:

```
Asset.new(symbol: ..., name: ..., ...)
```

This requires having a backing table, migration, and the usual ActiveRecord prerequisites.

If you're inheriting from a class you often have to pay close attention to what you're allowed to do, and what you're forbidden from doing. In the case of `ActiveRecord::Base` by way of `ApplicationRecord`, there is already an `initialize` method which has specific requirements.

If you want a simple class with no connection to the database, strip the inheritance. An idiomatic version of this code looks like:

```
class Asset
  def initialize(symbol, name, type, listed_on, face_value)
    @name = name
    @symbol = symbol
    @type = type
    @face_value = face_value
    @listed_on = listed_on
  end
end
```